# I think this is possible to send data in response to the post request. Any disadvantage?

Tags: mysql, node.js, post, get, request

I can understand post request is for sending data to the server. Moreover, the server responds with a success or error message. However, if we send data in response to post request after saving data, instead of creating separate get requests for fetching data.

I think this will enhance the speed of the system. we can save time and code of get request from the server-side as well as from the client side. Thanks for your suggestions and solution in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example in code?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in general in returning data from a POST request directly.

The main drawback is that, in an interactive browser setting, a page reload request will also re-submit the POST data.

That's the main reason why nowadays POST usually just responds with a status code and a redirect header that initiates another GET request.

That way a reload will only redo the GET request, and not the POST part (which might modify data in an unwanted way)